# Can the Cli service exist on each Org that installed in different machine (Hyperledger Fabric)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I wanna each machine that in a network of hyperledger fabric (using docker swarm) can execute the cli service. But, i don't found any reference for this issues. If someone know the solution of this issue, please help me